# Module build failed, Laravel 6 project

Tags: laravel, npm

I have created new project in laravel 6 and after installing npm I ran `npm run watch`, I'm getting this error.

```
Ahmed@DESKTOP-G216VK0 MINGW64 /c/laragon/www/larabiz
$ npm run watch

> @ watch C:\laragon\www\larabiz
> npm run development -- --watch


> @ development C:\laragon\www\larabiz
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"        

10% building 1/1 modules 0 active
webpack is watching the files…

98% after emitting SizeLimitsPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                         9:37:44 PM
 error  in ./resources/js/app.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Package exports for 'C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:485:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\debug.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at requireModule (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:165:12)
    at loadPreset (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:83:17)
    at createDescriptor (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)      
    at C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:58:104
    at cachedFunction (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:62:27)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\gensync\index.js:244:28)
    at sync (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\gensync\index.js:84:14)
    at presets (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:29:84)
    at mergeChainOpts (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:320:26)
    at C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:283:7

 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

       Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/app.css   0 bytes  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
  /js/app.js  7.86 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app

ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Package exports for 'C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:485:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\debug.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:914:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at requireModule (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:165:12)
    at loadPreset (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\plugins.js:83:17)
    at createDescriptor (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:58:104
    at cachedFunction (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\caching.js:62:27)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\gensync\index.js:244:28)
    at sync (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\gensync\index.js:84:14)
    at presets (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-descriptors.js:29:84)
    at mergeChainOpts (C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:320:26)
    at C:\laragon\www\larabiz\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\config-chain.js:283:7
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss /js/app[0]
```

`Package.json` file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {

        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "webpack": "^4.41.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the exact same error after trying to setup a brand new Laravel 6 installation.

Comment: Downgrade bable version - ``` "babel-core": "^6.26.0" ```

Comment: fwiw, I'm in a nativescript project and getting the same error. Looks to be something to do with babel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheers, I ran into this issue today.

`edit: Before I did this I tried downgrading babel and upgrading node etc, that did not work for me`

What I did was to uninstall nodejs and remove the npm and npm-cache folder from AppData
and rebooted.
Then reinstall nodejs.

Voilá, it works

Comment: I just uninstalled Node.js, then installed node.js in last TLS version, and removed those npm folders in C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Roaming and voilá!

Answer (score 2):

Please note that I resolved the problem by first upgrading to `nodejs` 13.6.0, and then performing these steps:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ rm -rf node_modules
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ npm cache clear --force
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ npm install cross-env
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ npm install 
vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:~$ npm run dev
```

Please note that I require the cross-env because I am developing with a Windows 10 host and an Ubuntu Vagrant VM.

For further details please see [@JLHwung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1490357/jlhwung)'s response at [Error: Package exports for <path to project folder>/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706130/error-package-exports-for-path-to-project-folder-node-modules-babel-helper-c)

Answer (score 1):

add in packege.json

> "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

For windows users, ff you use chocolatey, just ran this in the terminal, reopen the terminal where you try do run dev and everything will work just great:

```
choco upgrade nodejs
```