# Error: Package exports for <path to project folder>/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath

Tags: node.js, express

I just created a new project folder and ran the following commands:

- npm init
- npm install express
- npm install express-react-views react
  react-dom

Created index.js with express imported and views for a sample jsx file. When I run on localhost, I get this error:

```
Error: Package exports for '<path_to_project_folder>/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:485:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<path_to_project_folder>/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/debug.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Module._compile (<path_to_project_folder>/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
```

In Oct 2019, I created an express app using the same steps ran, and found there is no such package (@babel/helper-compilation-targets), and it ran fine.

I'm not sure what is wrong. Can anyone help to advice? 
Thank you!

Comment: Seems duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706004/module-build-failed-laravel-6-project

Comment: Recommended: Delete clean cache node_module and node gyp files. and re install in the documents folder. Where node has all the access. Some time node cant work due to permission. rm -rf ~/.npm && npm cache clear -f

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, but with a fresh Laravel 6 installation. @xdeepakv your proposed fix didn't do it for me. :( Any other idea's?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Had the same issue. Updating the node.js fixed that for me

Comment: Updating from 13.0.1 to 13.6.0 fixed this. Thx!

Comment: Worked here too! **Don't forget to close the terminal instance after node upgrade and reopen another one before building! and btw, the command to update node is `nvm install node` (if you have nvm, if you don't you should)**

Answer (score 6):

It will be fixed on babel v7.8.4, see https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/11006. Before a new babel release is cut, please upgrade node.js to >=13.2.0, which incorporates the necessary [upstream fix](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/29978/files#diff-76195ce57689942222a27f0dbda6d3b7R495).

Note that node.js 12 is *not* affected unless you have *manually* toggled on `--experimental-modules` flag. If that is the case, please also upgrade node.js to >=13.2.0.

Answer (score 4):

So this seems to be an incompatibility between Babel and Node.js. The general solution is to switch to nodejs 12 (e.g. if you are using `nvm`), since it only affected nodejs 13:

```
nvm install 12
nvm use 12
```

However, for my Rails 6 application this was not sufficient alone, as I still got the same error. Telling Yarn about the node version I am expecting to use was necessary in addition to that. So I added this to the `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "12.14.1"
}
```