# Upgraded Gatsby and Now Getting BABEL Error -Package exports do not define a '.' subpath

Tags: babeljs, gatsby, static-site

> ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
>
> [BABEL] .cache\develop-static-entry.js: Package exports for
>   '\node_modules@babel\helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.'
>   subpath

Tried upgrading NPM and cleaning out the NPM cache, but this did not work.

Before the gatsby upgrade, did not have this issue

## Gatsby INFO

```
  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18362
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 13.0.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 6.13.6 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Edge: 44.18362.449.0
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.18.21 => 2.18.21
    gatsby-cli: ^2.8.26 => 2.8.26
    gatsby-image: ^2.2.38 => 2.2.38
    gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls: ^2.1.19 => 2.1.19
    gatsby-plugin-config: ^1.0.7 => 1.0.7
    gatsby-plugin-google-analytics: ^2.1.32 => 2.1.32
    gatsby-plugin-gtag: ^1.0.12 => 1.0.12
    gatsby-plugin-metomic: 0.0.2 => 0.0.2
    gatsby-plugin-playground: ^1.0.6 => 1.0.6
    gatsby-plugin-react-head: ^1.1.0 => 1.1.0
    gatsby-plugin-s3: ^0.2.5 => 0.2.5
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^2.1.27 => 2.1.27
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.3.13 => 2.3.13
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^2.2.25 => 2.2.25
    gatsby-remark-images: ^3.1.42 => 3.1.42
    gatsby-remark-relative-images: ^0.2.3 => 0.2.3
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.1.46 => 2.1.46
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^2.6.48 => 2.6.48
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.3.12 => 2.3.12
```

Comment: NOTE: when using Gatsby BUILD, the error is only slightly different: 

 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating JavaScript bundles failed

[BABEL] \.cache\production-app.js: Package exports for '\node_modules\@babel\helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you either need to upgrade to `babel v7.8.4` or `nodejs 13.6.0`.  For details please see [Error: Package exports for <path to project folder>/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets' do not define a '.' subpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59706130/error-package-exports-for-path-to-project-folder-node-modules-babel-helper-c)

If you upgrade `nodejs` then please remember to clear your cache:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
$ npm cache clear --force
$ npm install 
$ npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade node to v12.14.1 or more, and the issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Took A Few steps based on reviewing the link question:

1. Upgrade Node
2. Delete Node_Modules folder in the project
3. Run npm install in the project

Then I was back in business. Thanks for the responses